# Homepage template in Prestashop? Where?

Tags: php, html, e-commerce, smarty, prestashop

I am used to developing WordPress sites but my new client insists on using Prestashop. I've installed it with a default template and don't know where to even start. It destroys me.

Luckily I just have to chenge the homepage, nothing more for today, so there will be more time to learn later.

**Could you please instruct me on which template (.tpl files?) should I modify to change the design of the homepage in Prestashop?** This template structure is completely foreign to me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: in PS 1.6 it is in `themes/yourTheme/index.tpl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really think you will need to have a quick look to our documentation:
[PrestaShop 1.6 Templating Documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Designer+Guide)

It will explain you how it was designed and how create/edit PrestaShop's templates.

Comment: Yes, I browsed through it, and it took me a few hours to understand everything. I didn't know that this problem was much wider than for example in WordPress.